# web services with spring in Ibm websphere Rational developer

Tags: spring, websphere, ibm-rad

I use RAD 8.5 build in web-service feature to create web services and run in websohere 8.It's no need third-party web services framework ,no set up in web.xml . now I need integrate it with spring .   I use load application context in my web services construction .I know it clumsy . who has the elegant solution  to integrate spring with it . Thanks . My code is below .

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService(
        name = "Test",
        targetNamespace = "http:///www.test.com",
        serviceName = "TestService",
        portName = "TestPort"

        )
public class TestWebservice {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "classpath*:**/applicationContext*.xml")

    public String sayHi(String inputStr){


        return "Hi " +  context.getbean("Testbao").sayHi( inputStr) ;

    } 
}
```

Comment: So are you running without a `web.xml` for your application?

Comment: the web.xml is very normal , no serverlet ,no listener information. I suppose websphere just use jws annotation to detect web services.

Comment: now I put <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener> in the web.xml , now I found 12:11:35:282 EDT] 00000017 WASAxis2Exten I   WSWS7037I: The /TestService URL pattern was configured for the TestWebservice servlet located in the testwebs.war web module. was loaded first before spring loaded into web application . It 's  possible load it after spring loaded first